# Сервер для игры

Tags: сервер

Я доделал несложную онлайн игру по типу шашек на Java и сервер Nodejs. Сейчас думаю над его улучшением.

Я прочитал, что лучше делать сервер на том языке, на котором и приложение. Но C# возможно будет лучше. Подскажите, на каком языке сделать сервер, если он будет запускаться на VPS. Я знаю Java и C#.

Comment: " лучше делать сервер на том языке, на котором и приложение" -- нет такого утверждения. Вообще серверная часть разрабатывается с учётом требований и подбирается с йчётом особенностей как правило. А в целом, для учебки - можно писать на том, на чём вам удобнее